# SQLalchemy issue in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

i am learning flask from youtube.in the current lecture we are using database

first we installed sqlalchemy
    `pip install flask-sqlalchemy`
then in my main flaskblog.py app

[image]

```
#url_for is for importing css files
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,flash,redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from forms import RegistrationForm,LoginForm 
app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY']='c3dfea8abf7e49794dfcdd1c8e02024d' #value is random


# /// means relative path from the curret path
#site.db will be created in the project directory
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///site.db'


#creating instance of database
db=SQLAlchemy(app)


#to create a user model
class User(db.Model):
    #adding colums for table
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)#max 20 characters.should be unique and compulsory
    email=db.Column(db.String(120),unique=True,nullable=False)
    image_file=username=db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False,default='default.jpg')
    password=db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)


    #creating relationship between user and post table
    #backref is adding column to Post model.
    posts=db.relationship('Post',backref='author',lazy=True)


    #how our object is prined
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}','{self.email}','{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title:db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True,nullable=False)
    date_posted=db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.utcnow) #saving dates automatically
    content=db.Column(db.text,nullabe=False)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'),nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}','{self.date_posted}')"
```

in vscode i am getting weird errors-
     Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Column' member,
     Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'Integer' member,
     Instance of 'SQLAlchemy' has no 'String' member, 
[image] 
i ignored it and the instructor told me to add this to terminal of current folder

```
$from flaskblog import db
cant read /var/mail/flaskblog
```

i dont know whats happening.need help as i cant move foward.
when i run the file
[image]
here is the insructors github page for full code-https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/Flask_Blog/04-Database/flaskblog.py

Comment: You have this `title:db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True,nullable=False)` instead of `title=db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True,nullable=False)`. This may not be the problem but it's a problem

Comment: corrected the typo but bot issue still exist.

Comment: oh yea that's not the problem :). `db` seems to be the culprit. Are those errors or warnings? I can't see your ui but it seems some sort of linter is saying that the `db` object does not have `Column`, `Integer` or `String` attributes. Did the code fail when you lunched the app?

Comment: all db is under red color.and also the "instance of 'SQLAlchemy' ..." is under problems menu.there are in total of 22 problems

Comment: Problem doesn't mean the code app won't lunch. I am just asking if the app fails to run at all

Comment: no it doesnt run.getting a lot of errors

Answer (score 0):

One reason I see why it's not running is (per the traceback), line 38 `db.text` should be `db.String`.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry made a very silly mistake of running the import db command from the bash and not the python console